# Does install4j support smart card EV code signing certificates

Tags: install4j

Just got an EV Code Signing certificate, it comes in a USB key and shows up in the windows certificate store when plugged in.  install4j does have an option to use a certificate from the windows certificate store when signing.

But when I tried to use this option, I got an error:

Caused by: com.install4j.d.k: org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException: cannot create signer: Key type not supported
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException: cannot create signer: Key type not supported
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key type not supported
    at jdk.crypto.mscapi/sun.security.mscapi.RSASignature.engineInitSign(RSASignature.java:533)

So, does install4j support these certificates?

And going further: using the key requires a PIN to be entered at the time of signing.

For automated builds, where the installers get built every night, how does install4j handle the PIN (there was no option that I could see in the project file)?

Comment: It seems strange that BouncyCastle should not be able to the process a key type of an EV certificate. Did you try the PKCS#11 option? Passwords are passed with the `--win-keystore-password` command line option https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/cli/compiler.html

Comment: I tried to use PKCS11, but got an error: java.io.IOException: The specified module could not be found.  The module is a Yubikey, the PKCS#11 dll that comes with it is libykcs11-1.dll.  I tested the dll with the keytool from Java using a config file that references it, and the keytool can read it without problems.

Comment: Do you have the entire stack trace? It may be in %TEMP%\install4j_error.log.

Comment: The stack trace is too long to post here, is there any other way that I can get it to you?

Comment: Please write to support@ej-technologies.com

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this [does work in principle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72085189/1124509), without PIN dialog popup, at least in this specific configuration:

- Sectigo EV Code Signing Certificate
- SafeNet eToken 5110

Answer (score 0):

We develop a JavaFX application on Mac.  We do all our work on Mac, but its deployed on Windows.

Our packaging and code-signing procedure is handled by install4j, and we use Sectigo for certificates.

Prior to January 2024, the code-signing certificate resided on a Mac machine, and we used a PFX file.  Recently, we switched to hardware-based, and Sectigo mailed us an HSM, "SafeNet eToken 5100/5110".

First we visited Sectigo site, where we downloaded and installed the Safenet program onto our Mac machine.  Safenet installed the dylib file at /usr/local/lib/ libeTPkcs11.dylib (which we pointed install4j to).

The HSM came with our certificate installed.  Sectigo then emailed us the related Root, Intermediate, and Cross-sign certificates, and we manually imported each one onto the token.  (note, the certificates Sectigo emailed us had “crt” extensions, and we changed them to “cer” extensions).

This worked for us.