# install4j: Automating Windows Extended Validation Code Signing and Apple Notarization on the same machine?

Tags: code-signing, install4j, hardware-security-module, safenet, notarization

We are considering to switch to an extended validation (EV) code signing certificate.

In order to fully automate the notarization with Apple, we had to switch our build machine to a Mac mini.

Reading up on the [EV code signing process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48946680/how-to-avoid-the-windows-defender-smartscreen-prevented-an-unrecognized-app-fro), and [how to automate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927895/automate-extended-validation-ev-code-signing), two questions arose:

### Can the password entry for the hardware token (HSM) be automated?

The [comment from Ingo Kegel on this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61616775/does-install4j-support-smart-card-ev-code-signing-certificates) seems to indicate that you can pass the HSM password via `--win-keystore-password=<password>` command line option.

Is that correct?

### Can a multi-platform build still happen on a single machine (the Mac mini)?

The [install4j help](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/concepts/codeSigning.html) mentions 'different platforms':

> On Windows, such a hardware token can be usually accessed through the
> Windows keystore. On a different platform, you have to choose the
> "Hardware security module PKCS #11 library" option and configure a
> native library that provides access to the keystore in the HSM through
> the PKCS #11 API.

Are there PKCS #11 libraries for MacOS? The library selection dialog asks for a DLL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The comment from Ingo Kegel on this SO question seems to indicate that you can
> pass the HSM password via --win-keystore-password= command line
> option.

Yes, that is correct. This option is available on non-Windows platforms as well for code signing of Windows executables.

> Can a multi-platform build still happen on a single machine (the Mac mini)?

Yes, a multi-platform build that involves notarization can only be performed on macOS, because Apple does not allow notarization requests except from macOS.

> Are there PKCS #11 libraries for MacOS? The library selection dialog asks for
> a DLL...

You need a library for your HSM, this will be a .so file on Linux or a *.dylib file on macOS. I have created an issue for the file chooser to show the correct file filter based on the current platform.

Whether such a library is available for macOS depends on the HSM. These libraries are loaded by the Java Cryptography Api (JCA) and install4j has no Windows-specific code in this respect.

Comment: Great, thank you! And just to double check: The win-keystore-password option is also intendend for the hardware module, not just a standard certificate?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that we managed to get this running (both Windows EV Code Signing and Apple Notarization automated on a Mac mini):

- Bought [Sectigo EV Code Signing Certificate](https://cheapsslsecurity.com/sectigo/sectigo-ev-code-signing-certificate.html)
- Attached the delivered **SafeNet eToken 5110** (USB Dongle) to the Mac mini
- Installed [SafeNet Authentication Client](https://sectigo.com/knowledge-base/detail/SafeNet-Download-for-Certificates-using-an-eToken-Smartcard/kA03l000000o6kL) (both on Mac mini and Windows for testing)
- Exported the certificate from the token to look at the certficate chain
- Exported the chain certificates from the Windows keystore (certmgr.msc)
- Imported the chain certificates onto the token (apparently some issuers will do this for you and deliver a token that not only contains the signing certificate but also it's chain)
- If the certificates cannot be added to the token, they can be provided to install4j in a directory via the compiler variable `sys.ext.certDir`
- Configured [install4j code signing](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/concepts/codeSigning.html) to use the PKCS11 library provided with the SafeNet Authentication Client: `/usr/local/lib/libeTPkcs11.dylib`
- For testing on Windows: `C:/Windows/System32/eTPKCS11.dll`
- Finally: No SmartScreen Message anymore

[image: cert-import]

[image: install4j-config]

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ingo Kegel's answer I had a quick look at common HSM tokens and their library support. Compiled here just for future reference (I have no way of actually testing this right now).

The USB tokens (HSM) of both DigiCert and Sectigo seem to be some version of the **SafeNet eToken**.

SafeNet apparently was bought by Gemalto, which in turn was bought by Thales.

Both DigiCert and Sectigo offer downloads for the SafeNet eToken drivers and authentication clients (for Window/MacOS/Linux). I couldn't find any downloads on the Thales website.

- [DigiCert SafeNet Downloads](https://knowledge.digicert.com/generalinformation/INFO1982.html)
- [Sectigo SafeNet Downloads](https://sectigo.com/knowledge-base/detail/SafeNet-Download-for-Certificates-using-an-eToken-Smartcard/kA03l000000o6kL)

This [post about signing PDF documents on MacOS Sierra using the SafeNet eToken 5100](https://kbpdfstudio.qoppa.com/how-to-setup-usb-smart-card-hardware-pkcs11-signing-on-mac/) has a screenshot showing the driver file:

```
/usr/local/lib/libeTPkcs11.dylib
```

[image]