# How would I export certificate chain from Windows to use with Install4j external certificate directory

Tags: java, code-signing, install4j

I've been using Install4j 8.0.11 to successfully code sign Mac and Windows installer files for years.  Our Windows certificate expired and I've received a new code signing certificate on YubiKey.  I can use the YubiKey to sign Windows exe files using Microsoft SignTool, but I cannot get Install4j to sign on my Mac using the YubiKey.  It complains the certificate chain is invalid.

I attempted to add the intermediate and root certificates to the YubiKey but I either didn't do it correctly or Install4j still doesn't recognize the chain.  I tried creating an external certificate folder (sys.ext.certDir) and having the certificate files in that folder but then Install4j complains that the certificate files must be at least 1024 bits.  Clearly I'm doing something wrong.  I found this related [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71868319/install4j-automating-windows-extended-validation-code-signing-and-apple-notariz) but it doesn't give detailed instructions for exporting certificates from Windows, for example what settings to use.  The code signing certificate is from SSL.com.

Comment: Can you try with the latest version of install4j?  It may give you more helpful instructions regarding the problem.

Comment: I get this error from Install4j 10.0.6 as well Build failed.

Cause: CompileException
       *** issued by SSL.com EV Code Signing Intermediate CA RSA R3 from /usr/local/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so does not contain the complete certificate chain.
       Please add root and intermediate certificates or point the compiler variable sys.ext.certDir to a directory with *.cer files.

Comment: "and having the certificate files in that folder but then Install4j complains that the certificate files must be at least 1024 bits" -> and that also still happens?